# State update in useReducer in react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hy... iam just learning react.. i have a doubt??

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
const initialState = { count: 0, val: 0 };
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FIRST": {
      return { ...state, count: state.count + 1, val: state.count + 10 };
    }
    default:
      console.error("invalid action type");
  }
}
function Learn() {
  const [{ count, val }, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  console.log(` count is ${count} and val=${val}}`);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "FIRST" })}>hellooo</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Learn;
```

my output is count=1,val=10 ..ie, expected val is 11. why val is not updated?? is state update in useReducer and useState is same??

for this state update am i need to use 2 dispatch function on button clicking..? one for count updating and another for val updating??

```
function handleClick(){
dispatch("countUpdate");
dispatch("valUpdate");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `val` is not updating? It goes from `0` to `10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your reducer function, you are updating the val based on the count value before it's updated. This is because both count and val are updated in the same return statement. When you calculate the new val, you are using state.count which is the old value of count.
To fix this, you should first update count and then calculate val based on the updated count. Here's how you can modify your reducer function to achieve this:**

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FIRST": {
      const newCount = state.count + 1;
      const newVal = newCount + 10;
      return { ...state, count: newCount, val: newVal };
    }
    default:
      console.error("invalid action type");
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now, when you dispatch the "FIRST" action, it will first increment count by 1 and then calculate val based on the new value of count, resulting in val being updated to 11 when count is 1.

For more detaill:- https://react.dev/reference/react/useReducer